# How to disable message encryption for gcp pubsub emulator?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

I'm using [the official GCP PubSub emulator](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator) to test integration locally.

I'd like to send messages via classic curl/postman tools but it is getting complicated because this emulator requires encryption of incoming messages.

For instance, if we send it like this:

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8091/v1/projects/my-project/topics/transactions:publish' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"messages":[{"data":"{\"foo\":\"baz\"}","attributes":{}}]}'
```

Then, I'm getting **400**:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Payload isn't valid for request.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

due to invalid incoming messages. It requires encryption and if I sniff the encrypted body it works.

But it is **overwhelming** to encrypt messages running it **locally**.

In order to disable encryption in GCP I can follow [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/encryption#disabling_and_re-enabling_keys) but it is not applicable to local emulators run - there is no GCP environment or I don't know how to do it.

Are there any options to disable emulator decryption? If not where to report it, there is no GitHub project for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it took time for me to understand, but I think you mixed 2 things: encryption and encoding.

The data value in PubSub isn't provided encrypted but encoded in base64. There isn't encryption required here. Base64 encoding is a raw encoding to prevent data loss, encoding type, special characters, binary data and boring compatibility things.

*Note: On your local computer with pubsub emulator, the data aren't encrypted at rest and in transit. On Google Cloud, with PubSub service, the data are encrypted in transit and at rest*

---

With curl you can use this command (with linux OS)

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8091/v1/projects/my-project/topics/transactions:publish' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw "{\"messages\":[{\"data\":\"$(echo "{\"foo\":\"baz\"}" | base64 -)\",\"attributes\":{}}]}"
```

*Yes, backslash are boring...*

I don't know how to do with postman